# Semantic UI - search autocomplete with dynamics input

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, laravel-5, semantic-ui

Having some problems with Semantic UI autocomplete.

I have an input with the **SEMANTIC UI** **search autocomplete** that works great but when im trying to use the same script with dynamic inputs the autocomplete is not working at all.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="ui search" id="tag">
      <div class="ui icon input">
         <input style="width:400px;" class="prompt" type="text"  name="tag[]">
           <i class="search icon"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="results"></div>
 </div> 
 <button type="button" id="create-tags" class="ui primary tiny button">Add Tag</button>
 <div id="dynamic"></div>
```

**SEMANTIC SEARCH SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tag').search({
        apiSettings: {
            url: '/autocomplete/{query}',
            onResponse: function(results) {
                var response = {
                    results : []
                };
                $.each(results, function(index, item) {
                    response.results.push({
                        title       : item.name,
                        description : item.description
                        //url       : item.html_url
                    });
                });
                return response;
            },
        },
          minCharacters : 3,
    });
});
```

**DYNAMIC INPUTS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#create-tags").click(function(e){
     $("#dynamic").append('<div class="ui search" id="tag"><div class="ui icon input"><input style="width:400px;" class="prompt" type="text"  name="tag[]" placeholder="Busqueda autocompletado para personajes"></div><div class="results"></div></div>');
   });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the existing search input? Then you could use **.clone()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to replicate the existing search input, you can use JQuery **.clone()** method. I've created a sample code below for your reference. You can still revise it to a more sophisticated code but my idea here is to make a deep copy of the existing search input.

Note that I've assigned a unique class to the new search input. This is to avoid unnecessary behavior in the newly created objects.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tag').search({
        apiSettings: {
            url: '/autocomplete/{query}',
            onResponse: function(results) {
                var response = {
                    results : []
                };
                $.each(results, function(index, item) {
                    response.results.push({
                        title       : item.name,
                        description : item.description
                        //url       : item.html_url
                    });
                });
                return response;
            },
        },
          minCharacters : 3,
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   var ctr_ = 0;
   $("#create-tags").click(function(e){
     ctr_++;
     var unique_id = 'tag'+ ctr_;
     $("#dynamic").append($('#tag').clone().addClass(unique_id));
     $('.'+ unique_id).search({
        apiSettings: {
            url: '/autocomplete/{query}',
            onResponse: function(results) {
                var response = {
                    results : []
                };
                $.each(results, function(index, item) {
                    response.results.push({
                        title       : item.name,
                        description : item.description
                        //url       : item.html_url
                    });
                });
                return response;
            },
        },
          minCharacters : 3,
    }).search('set value', '');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui search" id="tag">
      <div class="ui icon input">
         <input style="width:400px;" class="prompt" type="text"  name="tag[]">
           <i class="search icon"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="results"></div>
 </div> 
 <button type="button" id="create-tags" class="ui primary tiny button">Add Tag</button>
 <div id="dynamic"></div>
```

Comment: Hey man works great Thanks!! Sorry i can vote for your answer :(

Comment: How to close/hide semantic ui search autocomplete when user click 'enter' button after entering keywords in search bar?